# Where can I download Jtalk or Smalltalk for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, smalltalk

I stumbled upon Jtalk here http://nicolaspetton.github.com/jtalk/index.html#download
but when clicking on download I have 404 so where else can I download it ?

Comment: The repository simply does not exist anymore.

Comment: yes but no backup somewhere and maybe someone has downloaded it and can put it somewhere else ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's alive and kicking but rebranded as amber smalltalk.

Be aware that it's still very early days and a small community so it'll help to know a bit of smalltalk and javascript too. Smalltalkers seem a friendly bunch though, so don't worry about asking beginner questions

http://amber-lang.net/

http://forum.world.st/Amber-f3824463.html